# How to sort an item of an multidimimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array in this form:

```
$parray[]=array('item_id'=>$rs->fields['item_id'], 
                'item_name'=>$rs->fields['item_name'],
                'item_count' =>$cs->fields['item_count'],
                'item_link'=>$rs->fields['item_link']);
```

and in a loop i set the values. so, i have them in $parray[0], $parray[1]...

now, how do I sort this array on item_count ?

for example:

```
$parray[0] = 0, "hello", 5, www.abc.abc
$parray[1] = 1, "hello2", 7, www.abc.abcab
$parray[2] = 2, "hello1", 8, www.abc.abca
$parray[3] = 3, "hello3", 2, www.abc.abcaaa
```

result should be

```
$parray[0] = 2, "hello1", 8, www.abc.abca
$parray[1] = 0, "hello", 5, www.abc.abc
$parray[2] = 1, "hello2", 3, www.abc.abcab
$parray[3] = 3, "hello3", 2, www.abc.abcaaa
```

how could i manage that ?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usort($parray, function ($a, $b){
    return $b['item_count'] - $a['item_count'];
});
print_r($parray);
```

Here's an alternative way:

```
$sub = array();
foreach ($parray as $item) {
    $sub[] = $item['item_count'];
}
array_multisort($sub, SORT_DESC, $parray);
print_r($parray);
```